# Why is Excel truncating my 16-digit numbers?

Tags: excel

If I type in a 16 digit number (format: number, no decimals) it changes the number on me. Example: 1234567812345678 changes the view to 1234567812345670.

If I type it in as a general format it changes the numbers above so it displays 1.23457E+15 but if you click on the cell, the display shows the last digit as a 0 instead of an 8 once again.

I opened the file on a different computer and same issue now with it. I have changed the auto correction and auto formatting all to no avail. Help!

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in Excel - numbers are stored with a precision of 15 digits.

[Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

(a bit futher down under 'Calculation specifications and limits')

Answer (score 2):

Excel follows the IEEE 754 specification on how to store and calculate floating-point numbers. Excel therefore stores only 15 significant digits in a number, and changes digits after the fifteenth place to zeroes.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells

Answer (score 0):

if the numbers are a form of code (or putting it another way, something not used for calculatons), you should format your whole column as text.

might need more info about your "file processing environment" if you encounter issues.

but if that 16 digits are for calculations (like add/sub/multipliy/divide) then it is as what the other 2 contributors said.